# GWT - ListBox - Trouble when i get index of the selected item

Tags: gwt, listbox

I have this ListBox (ComboBox) on GWT :

```
final ListBox category_2=new ListBox();
category_2.setStyleName("article_combo");
category_2.addItem("----------", "0");
category_2.addItem("1° Element", "1");
category_2.addItem("2° Element", "2");
category_2.addItem("----------", "0");
category_2.addItem("3° Element", "3");
category_2.addItem("4° Element", "4");
category_2.addItem("----------", "0");
category_2.addItem("5° Element", "5");
category_2.addItem("----------", "0");
category_2.addItem("6° Element", "6");
category_2.addItem("7° Element", "7");
category_2.addItem("8° Element", "8");
```

If i try to get the Index of the selected idem with

```
category_2.getSelectedIndex()
```

it returns to me the index of the category_2 (but it refeers to the array index, not the index setted by me).

Example: if I select 5° Element it doesn't return "5", but "7". How can I get the index set by myself? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hir markzz,

You would need to do something like:

```
int index = category_2.getSelectedIndex();
String myValue = category_2.getValue(index);
```

You should really take a look to the [documentation](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html)

Comment: Yes, this will works. But what i need is get the index, not the value. I don't see the getIndex(index) function :)

Comment: the addItem sets a description and a value. The index is set by the order you add the elements. getSelectedIndex returns you the index of the selected element. getValue returns the value of the specified index. I think that's the 'index'you want ;)

Comment: ohh...i confused "value" with "index". Yes now it works! thanks